# Extract approximation and detail coefficients

Tags: python, wavelet, homework, decomposition

I am a student and would like to know how to extract the approximation and detail coefficients (A5, D5, D4, D3, D2 and D1) after an applied DWT decomposition dB5 (Daubechies 5, level = 5)?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds quite doable, reading the online documentation, for instance:
[Multilevel DWT, IDWT and SWT](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/regression/multilevel.html), by adapting the example given:

```
>>> import pywt
>>> x = [3, 7, 1, 1, -2, 5, 4, 6]
>>> db1 = pywt.Wavelet('db1')
>>> cA3, cD3, cD2, cD1 = pywt.wavedec(x, db1)
>>> print(cA3)
[ 8.83883476]
>>> print(cD3)
[-0.35355339]
>>> print(cD2)
[ 4.  -3.5]
>>> print(cD1)
[-2.82842712  0.         -4.94974747 -1.41421356]
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you get the rest of the approximation coefficients?

The `pywt.wavelt` only gives the highest level of the approximation coefficients (if level is set to 5 we only get cA5) as far as I understood.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/51174)